# csquotes + biblatex: `\blockquote` behaves unexpectedly when using `\citefield`

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

- This seems to be about the combination of the two packages [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and [`csquotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes).
- I use the `\blockquote` command from the `csquotes` package to set a quote that has several lines (more than `csquotes` option `threshold`). The expected behavior is that the quote is printed in **display mode**.
- However, this is not the case when I use the `biblatex` command `\citefield` as shown in the MWE below. The same happens when I try `\blockcquote` (additional `c`) instead of `\blockquote`.
- **Question:** Why does `\blockquote` not recognize the need for display mode when `\citefield` is used inside the `\blockquote` command?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[threshold = 3, thresholdtype = lines]{csquotes} % "3" and "lines" is the default anyway.

\usepackage{blindtext}

% https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  abstract = {\blindtext},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{\textbackslash citefield\{key\}\{abstract\}}}
\blockquote[][]{\citefield{key}{abstract}}

\section{\texttt{\textbackslash blindtext}}
\blockquote[][]{\blindtext}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(Taken from the [`csquotes` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes), Version v5.2l, 2021-02-22)*

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You're welcome! I also forget from  time to time to check what I've typed, and am quite grateful when someone has corrected…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` disables its citation commands for the duration of measuring blockquote contents. This avoids all `biblatex`-related side-effects of executing cite commands once for measuring the contents and then for typesetting it. (You would for example end up with undesirable "ibidem" citations in the typeset blockquote. Other counting and tracking features would be off.)

If you absolutely need to measure the text generated by `biblatex` in your blockquote, you can re-enable its commands also for the measuring step. But keep in mind that things might go horribly wrong if you use more context-sensitive `\cite` commands in blockquote. (See the example in the third section, where the "ibid." in the output makes it appear as though `sigfridsson` was cited again, even though we actually cited `key`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\usepackage[threshold = 3, thresholdtype = lines]{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\real@blx@thecheckpunct\blx@thecheckpunct
  \gappto\blockquote@parsehook{\let\blx@thecheckpunct\real@blx@thecheckpunct}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author    = {Author, A.},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  abstract  = {\blindtext},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{\texttt{\textbackslash citefield\{key\}\{abstract\}}}
\blockquote[][]{\citefield{key}{abstract}}

\section{\texttt{\textbackslash blindtext}}
\blockquote[][]{\blindtext}

\section{Ooops}
First \autocite{key} and \autocite{sigfridsson}
\blockquote[][]{Lorem ipsum \autocite{key}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Two blockquotes as desired]

Comment: +1: So it's not a bug, it's actually a feature! Thanks.